# MPAndroidChart not updating MarkerView from background task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, mpandroidchart

I have a `MarkerView` class which looks like this:

```
public class InfoMarkerView extends MarkerView {

    TextView tv;
    LineChart mChart;

    public InfoMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource, LineChart chart) {
        super(context, layoutResource);
        mChart = chart;
    }

    @Override
    public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        tv.setText("Marker set in refreshContent");

        MyBackgroundTask myTask = new MyBackgroundTask(this);    //extends AsyncTask
        myTask.execute();

    }

    //callback from MyBackgroundTask
    public void myBackgroundTaskFinished(BackgroundTaskResult r) {
        tv.setText("Marker changed in myBackgroundTaskFinished");
        mChart.invalidate();   //doesn't really seem to change anything
    }
```

After callback is called, `TextView` is successfully updated (I can see that in Watch window) but changes are not visible in chart interface. What am I missing here? What should I do to refresh `TextView`?

Comment: where is the chart data updated?

Comment: @Hala.m there is another class for that. Does it matter?

Comment: maybe we need to see how the whole code is executed maybe it something  in there

Comment: @Hala.m nothing special. Some test data is set on program start and never changed. Chart displays correctly, I can highlight data points.

Comment: this code doesn't have any problems , I think it might be on another class or the chart itself unless the chart reference is invalid like the view is recreated or something

Comment: @Hala.m synchronous TextView update works fine - `BackgroundTaskResult r =  myTask.execute().get(3000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` in `refreshContent` procedure. Seems like chart object is not being updated when MarkerView is changed from other thread. Some internal workings of `MPAndroidChart` we are not aware of?

Comment: yeah that is my concern that this chart is not the right reference but I don't know need to see the full code

Comment: @Hala.m you were right - there was something else going on. View was refreshed multiple times and race condition was created. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `refreshContent()` is being executed not only every time user highlights a point in chart (as I was assuming), but also when moving and interacting with the chart. This created multiple updates for the same point in the chart and, consequently, race condition - `refreshContent()` updated the value back to initial immediately after background task executed and value change was never seen.

Now I am tracking X value being updated and if it's not changed I do not update it:

```
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    if (e.getX() == mLastRefreshedX) return;
    ...
```

Works like it should to.